# Lightbox not firing on two links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not the best with Javascript so be kind! I have 4 links which each in turn fire up a simple lightbox, the first 2 show their associated lightbox windows but the last 2 just show the black overlay and not the white box? As far as I can see there are no differences?

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showpopInfo">INFO</a></li>
<li>-</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showpopTips">TIPS</a></li>
<li>-</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showpopGallery">GALLERY</a></li>
<li>-</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="showpopContact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Here are the popups:

```
<!-- INFO POPUP -->
<div id="lightInfo" class="white_content">
    <a href ="javascript:void(0)" class="hidepop textright">Close</a>
    Info
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>


<!-- TIPS POPUP -->
<div id="lightTips" class="white_content">
    <a href ="javascript:void(0)" class="hidepop textright">Close</a>
    Tips
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

    <!-- GALLERY POPUP -->
    <div id="lightGallery" class="white_content">
        <a href ="javascript:void(0)" class="hidepop textright">Close</a>
        Gallery
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>


        <!-- CONTACT POPUP -->
        <div id="lightContact" class="white_content">
            <a href ="javascript:void(0)" class="hidepop textright">Close</a>
            CONTACT
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(".showpopInfo").click(function(){
    $("#lightInfo").show();
    $("#fade").show();
});
$(".hidepop").click(function(){
    $("#lightInfo").hide();
    $("#fade").hide();
});

$(".showpopTips").click(function(){
    $("#lightTips").show();
    $("#fade").show();
});
$(".hidepop").click(function(){
    $("#lightTips").hide();
    $("#fade").hide();
});

$(".showpopGallery").click(function(){
    $("#lightGallery").show();
    $("#fade").show();
});
$(".hidepop").click(function(){
    $("#lightGallery").hide();
    $("#fade").hide();
});

$(".showpopContact").click(function(){
    $("#lightContact").show();
    $("#fade").show();
});
$(".hidepop").click(function(){
    $("#lightContact").hide();
    $("#fade").hide();
});
```

Comment: Is your html correct? Divs with id lightTips, lightGallery and lightContact are not closed.

Comment: That will probably be why! Sorry holding a baby and trying to code is not the one!